# Concat on ng-model in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a problem with an ng-model, I want to create a "dynamic" ng-model with an $index, inside a ng-repeat.

I call an API and that response an object, with the following structure:

```
{
 rules: {
   rule1: "value1",
   rule2: "value2"
 }
}
```

I am trying to put it dynamically into ng-model like this.

```
<input type="text" ng-model='dc.dataToPass.rules["rule"+$index+1]' ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" required />
```

But does not work properly because does not show anything.

Comment: specify your problem. What does it mean "not work properly"? Do you get an error? What is in your console logs? Etc.

Comment: I do not get any errors, just simply does not show anything on my screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple bracket would solve your problem.

It is forcing creation of `"rule01"` what you need is `"rule1"`

```
<input type="text" ng-model='dc.dataToPass.rules["rule"+($index+1)]' ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" required />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dzw1hgLc/